# Installing React Native 0.70.6 on React 18.2

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've started a brand new react native project. When I attempt to install react native, I get dependency resolution errors. Could there be an issue with react 18.2 and react-native 0.70.6?
What is the best versions to use? Should I start with react 17?

```
npm install react-native
```

I receive the following output:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native@0.70.6
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/core@6.4.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/core
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/core@"^6.4.5" from @react-navigation/native@6.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!       @react-navigation/native@"^6.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@react-navigation/elements, ...)
npm ERR!   12 more (@react-navigation/elements, ...)
```

From my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Comment: are you new to react-native and making new project?

Comment: do `npm install react-native@latest`

Answer (score 2):

As of `react-native@0.70.6`, you should be using React 18.1.0:

```
npm install "react@18.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get correct and match version with react, then you have to run `npx react-native init YourProjectName`. Do not install each of them one by one, unless you know the match compatible version from each react native. Please re-read from official RN documentation.

The Simplest and easiest way , you just run `npx react-native init YourProjectName`

If you want to get simple react native boilerplate, You can install from handidev boilerplate. It is already used latest react native version.

for [typescript version](https://github.com/handi-dev/react-native-typescript-boilerplate):
`npx react-native init MyAppName --template @handidev/react-native-typescript-boilerplate`

for javascript plain version:
`npx react-native init MyApp --template @handidev/react-native-typescript-boilerplate`

Reference:

1. Official Documentation - https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
2. React Native Boilerplate - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handidev/react-native-boilerplate
3. React Native Typescript Boilerplate: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handidev/react-native-typescript-boilerplate